# Could I set custom ID in firestore?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Before, I used real-time DB, but now I need to change to use firestore.

when I doing writing data in real-time DB, I using this methods.

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
String userid = firebaseUser.getUid();
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userid);
HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put("id", userid);
hashMap.put("email", email);
hashMap.put("username", username);
```

So the data will show like this

```
  "Users" : {
    "02nfE2JziDgzxZwYpmCwQ20QwQ93" : {
      "email" : "sowtp12pushcivet@gmail.com",
      "id" : "02nfE2JziDgzxZwYpmCwQ20QwQ93",
      "username" : "AAA"
    },
```

But when I use firestore, it's will show this

```
  "Users" : {
    "u93AclSJJiLQBdfcK2st" : {
      "email" : "sowtp12pushcivet@gmail.com",
      "id" : "02nfE2JziDgzxZwYpmCwQ20QwQ93",
      "username" : "AAA"
    },
```

Could I change `u93AclSJJiLQBdfcK2st` to `02nfE2JziDgzxZwYpmCwQ20QwQ93`, if it's can change it, how do I do?

this is my code.

```
db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put("id", userid);
hashMap.put("email", email);
hashMap.put("username", username);

db.collection("Users").add(hashMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `add()` Firestore generates a new document ID. It is the equivalent of calling `push()` for the Realtime Database API.

If you want to specify your own document ID, don't call `add` but pass use `document("yourNewId").set()` instead:

```
db.collection("Users").document(userid).set(hashMap)...
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [setting a document value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#java).